# On Ubuntu 20.04, DHCP keeps overwriting static address assigned via Network Manager

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dhcp

I have properly configured the interface with this yaml file:

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses: [192.168.174.131/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.174.2
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.174.0
          via: 192.168.173.131
    lo:
      addresses: [127.0.0.1/24,0.0.0.0/24]
```

and the route table shows the access to the VMNAT8 address (which is 192.168.174.20):

```
my_env) ubuntu@ubuntu2010:/etc/netplan$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens33
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.174.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens33
```

The problem is after a period of time, an ipv6 address is assigned to ens33, as if the dhclient ran and ignored the static configuration.

The question is how to prevent this from happening?  I have not found a solution suggested on the various sites which describe related issues.

Comment: This appears to be a VMware Virtual Machine and I think you mean VMnet8  (not VMNAT8).  Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to describe, as IPv6 addresses **do not** overwrite IPv4 addresses in any way.

Comment: @jhallesy - Can you answer our questions please.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want IPv6 addresses, add to the yaml file the following lines for ens33:

```
dhcp6: no
accept-ra: no
```